# Python equivalent to MATLAB's Excel writing function, xlswrite()

Tags: python, excel, matlab

I've Googled around for about an hour, and no answer has been satisfactory (or even less than a year old...), but I'm trying to find a way to simply paste values to an Excel sheet WITHOUT modifying anything else - no resetting formatting, no overwriting sheets to be blank (Pandas), no deleting images (openpyxl), just do something simple.

I've grown pretty frustrated because Python seems to be able to do everything so far, but MATLAB has a one-line function, `xlswrite()` where I can write values to an Excel sheet without messing up anything else. Give it an array of values and the top-left cell, and it does exactly what it's supposed to.

Short of copy-pasting the formatting for every cell of every sheet for every workbook in my project, what other options do we have? Is there just a `xlPasteValuesOnly()` or something? Anything?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The following commands update an existing Excel file (tables.xlsx) adding pandas' dataframes (df1, df2) to new tabs.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('tables.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('tables.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df1.to_excel(writer, 'df1')
df2.to_excel(writer, 'df2')

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for submitting an answer! Unfortunately, I tried this code before already. I tried it again exactly as you wrote it (with my own DataFrame for df1) and it completely erased the other sheets... from my original post: "...no overwriting sheets to be blank (Pandas)...".

Also, it overwrote the cell formatting.

Just to reiterate, I have multiple methods to write to excel (I've used xlsxwriter, Pandas, openpyxl). What I'm looking for is a "paste values only" method without affecting the cell formatting. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. In my case, it does not erase existing sheets. But you are right about overwriting cell formatting. I guess you already know that pandas can do some styling https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html